# Series sum and integral inaccuracy problem

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

Well, it happened that math is not my field. Having a vague concept in general I have been struggling for a few hours with the exercise. In general, I want to calculate how much interest a man have paid up to the given period.

But the problem is not related to the type of exercise. To be specific, my question is, does a sum with defined limits is integrable? If it is, why does the integration gives inaccurate answer compared to the sum?

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{x=0}^{28}(1+1,014^{-x})\approx4.967
\end{eqnarray*}

and

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^{28}(1+1,014^{-x})\,dx = (x+71.9274\cdot e^{-0.0139029\cdot x})|_{x=0}^{x=28} \approx 4.80655
\end{eqnarray*}

Should I expect, to make such integral from series to give me exact answer as sum?

Calculations were performed using WolframAlpha online tool.

Any help is appreciated.